# Rust/rocket pass variable to endpoints

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

Not to my preference but I'm forced to write some Rust today so I'm trying to create a Rocket instance with only one endpoint but, on that endpoint I need to access a variable that is being created during main. The variable takes a long time to be instantiated so that's why I do it there.

My problem is that I can;t find a way to pass it safely. Whatever I do, the compiler complaints about thread safety even though the library appears to be thread safe: https://github.com/brave/adblock-rust/pull/130 (commited code is found on my local instance)

This is the error tat I get:

```
   |
18 | / lazy_static! {
19 | |     static ref rules_engine: Mutex<Vec<Engine>> = Mutex::new(vec![]);
20 | | }
   | |_^ `std::rc::Rc<std::cell::RefCell<lifeguard::CappedCollection<std::vec::Vec<u64>>>>` cannot be sent between threads safely
   |
```

...and this is my code:

```
#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene, decl_macro)]

#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket;

use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, BufRead};
use std::path::Path;

use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use std::sync::Mutex;

use adblock::engine::Engine;
use adblock::lists::FilterFormat;

use rocket::request::{Form, FormError, FormDataError};

lazy_static! {
    static ref rules_engine: Mutex<Vec<Engine>> = Mutex::new(vec![]);
}

fn main() {
    if !Path::new("./rules.txt").exists() {
        println!("rules file does not exist")
    } else {
        println!("loading rules");

        let mut rules = vec![];

        if let Ok(lines) = read_lines("./rules.txt") {
            for line in lines {
                if let Ok(ip) = line {
                    rules.insert(0, ip)
                }
            }

            let eng = Engine::from_rules(&rules, FilterFormat::Standard);
            rules_engine.lock().unwrap().push(eng);
            rocket().launch();
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, FromForm)]
struct FormInput<> {
    #[form(field = "textarea")]
    text_area: String
}

#[post("/", data = "<sink>")]
fn sink(sink: Result<Form<FormInput>, FormError>) -> String {
    match sink {
        Ok(form) => {
            format!("{:?}", &*form)
        }
        Err(FormDataError::Io(_)) => format!("Form input was invalid UTF-8."),
        Err(FormDataError::Malformed(f)) | Err(FormDataError::Parse(_, f)) => {
            format!("Invalid form input: {}", f)
        }
    }
}

fn rocket() -> rocket::Rocket {
    rocket::ignite().mount("/", routes![sink])
}

fn read_lines<P>(filename: P) -> io::Result<io::Lines<io::BufReader<File>>>
    where P: AsRef<Path>, {
    let file = File::open(filename)?;
    Ok(io::BufReader::new(file).lines())
}
```

Any way of having the `eng` available inside the `sink` endpoint method?

Comment: I'm not used to Rocket, but in many other frameworks there's some way to pass the same state to all routes. I see that [Rocket probably has this as well](https://rocket.rs/v0.4/guide/state/)

Comment: I get the same error using states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Rc` is not thread safe, even behind a mutex. It looks like `Rc` is used in `eng.blocker.pool.pool` which is a [`lifeguard::Pool`](https://docs.rs/lifeguard/0.6.0/lifeguard/struct.Pool.html). So no, the `Engine` is not thread safe (at least by default).

Fortunately, it appears that the adblock crate has a [feature](https://github.com/brave/adblock-rust/blob/master/Cargo.toml#L86) called "object-pooling", which enables that specific functionality. Removing that feature will (hopefully) make it thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

Rocket makes it really easy to share resources between routes (and also between `main` or any other thread you might have spawned from `main`). They call their mechanism `state`. Check out its documentation [here](https://rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/guide/state/).

To give a short example of how it works:
You create your type that you want to share in your application and `manage` an instance of that type in the instance of `rocket` that you use for your application. In the guide they give this example:

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::AtomicUsize;

struct HitCount {
    count: AtomicUsize
}

rocket::build().manage(HitCount { count: AtomicUsize::new(0) });
```

In a route then you access the resource like this (again from the guide):

```
use rocket::State;

#[get("/count")]
fn count(hit_count: &State<HitCount>) -> String {
    let current_count = hit_count.count.load(Ordering::Relaxed);
    format!("Number of visits: {}", current_count)
}
```

While I learnt rocket I needed to share a struct that contained a `String`, which is not thread safe per se. That means you need to wrap it into a `Mutex` before you can `manage` it with rocket.

Also, as far as I understand, only one resource of any specific type can be shared with `manage`. But you can just create differently named wrapper types in that case and work around that limitation.