# Remove crate feature

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm loading a crate in my project and this crate has a feature called `object-pooling` that is not thread safe. [Someone suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63763318/1515697) I remove this functionality from the crate but I don't know how to do that. Is there a special entry that I can add to my Cargo.toml file and disables `features` from dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax in your CARGO.TOML is:

```
crate_name = {version="version_numer", features=[feature1, feature2]}
```

If you want or don't want to have a specific feature you can adapt the `features` list.

Check out the crates documentation or sourcecode if you want to know which features provide which functionality.

You can find the available features of your specific crate here:
https://github.com/brave/adblock-rust/blob/master/Cargo.toml#L86

Comment: Some features may be enabled by default. These can be disabled using `default-features = false`. More problematically, some of your dependencies may depend on the same version of `adblock-rust` and enable the features you don't want, in which case you don't really have a way to disable them. You can only ensure a feature is _enabled_, not that it is _disabled_.

Comment: @SvenMarnach good point, maybe you can add this to my answer

Comment: Seems like the right answer - doesn't seem to work for me though but that's another issue I guess.

Comment: I don't agree - it basically says "yes there is a way" without actually answering the question!